# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with two BouncyCastle jars

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have included 2 BC jars into my project: *bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar* and *bcprov-jdk15on-157.jar*.

As the first line in code I have added:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Exception occurs on the line:

```
JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest csrNew = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest(request);

By the way it is imported: import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest;
```

But I am still getting :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/JcaJceHelper
>       at implementation.Util.generateCSR(Util.java:396)

NetBeans found class regularly, but when I run project exception happens.

Is there any way how could I regularly include both of these two BouncyCastle jars?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Error is coming for `org/bouncycastle/jcajce/JcaJceHelper`, not for `org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest`.

***Problem:*** versions of jar files you are using. ***`bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47` is version 1.47, whereas `bcprov-jdk15on-1.57` is version 1.57.***

`org/bouncycastle/jcajce/JcaJceHelper` was available in `bcprov-jdk15on-1.47` but it is not available in `bcprov-jdk15on-1.57`. In version 1.57, it is available as `org/bouncycastle/jcajce/util/JcaJceHelper`.

Netbeans is unable to detect the issue, because this issue would come only when you run the code. It will not be caught at compile time.

***Solution:***
Yes, you can use both jars together. Just use the same version. Either use `bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57` **OR** use `bcprov-jdk15on-1.47`.

Comment: Thank you for great response! I succeeded by adding bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: this answer has some errors. but anyhow, the version control of bouncycastle is extremely poor and unprofessional

Comment: @francogrex let me know the errors. It's better to correct.